# Can't fire Journey Event using Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I know its very straightforward and I myself have done it many times before. But this time I don't know why its not working. Want to make sure if something has changed with the recent SFMC releases.
I created a very simple Journey with just one email activity.
Then created an Automation Program with Fire Event activity.
Entered a record in the DE.
Ran the Automation Program manually. It completed but nothing happens in the journey

What could I be missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be fired when ever contacts are admitted into the api event?

Comment: Your question did ring a bell in my head. Right now am using API event in my Journey. Is that not supported with Automation Program. Right ? Should I be using an Audience entry event? Previously Contact Data Event use to work with Automation but now its on its way to retire

Comment: I think that a diff issue. To my understanding you API source system is firing the event.

Answer (score 1):

I was using API event for the journey which is not supported with Automation Program. I changed it to Email Audience entry event and it worked perfectly.